# Highlighting HTML table cells using values from database

Tags: php

I want to highlight the time values in HTML table by comparing it to the database table for a given date.

I am trying this code

```
<?php

     function getdata($start_date, $timevalue)
     {
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "test";

        $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
        $result = $con->query( "SELECT * FROM booking" );
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                if(($row['datefrom']==$start_date) && ($row['timefrom']<=$timevalue && $row['timeto']>=$timevalue)){
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
     }

    $start_date = "2019-07-11";
    $end_date = "2019-07-15";
    $tmfrm = strtotime("07:00:00");
    $tmto = strtotime("15:00:00");

    echo "<table border='1'>";
     while (strtotime($start_date) <= strtotime($end_date))
     {
        echo "<tr><td>".$start_date."</td>";
        for($t=$tmfrm; $t<=$tmto; $t+=1800)
        {
            $timevalue=date("H:i:s", $t);
            if (getdata($start_date, $timevalue)==1){
            echo "<td bgcolor='red'>". $timevalue  . "<br></td>";
            }else
            {
                echo "<td bgcolor='green'>".  $timevalue  . "<br></td>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        $start_date = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 days", strtotime($start_date)));
      }
      echo "</table>"; 
?>
```

below is the table with sample data

```
booking
--------------------------------------------
roomno | datefrom   |  timefrom | timeto   | 
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-11 |  07:00:00 | 10:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-11 |  11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-12 |  11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-13 |  11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-14 |  07:00:00 | 10:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-15 |  10:30:00 | 13:30:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-11 |  13:30:00 | 14:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
```

in the output which I am getting, it is only highlighting times from 07:00 to 10:00 on 2019-07-11 whereas it should highlight times for other dates also including the other time (14:00 to 15:00) for 2019-07-11. (see figure). What's wrong with the logic?

[image: view output here]

Comment: I'd be tempted to call the db results just once rather than in a loop

Comment: Your code only ever compares against the very first record returned from the database - because you are _exiting_ the function with `return` in either case, so all other records do not get iterated over by the while loop to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution. All I have to do is to modify the getdata() function to work without loop. I specified the condition with the select statement instead of checking it in the loop with if statement. Following is the modified code:

```
function getdata($start_date, $timevalue)
     {
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "";
        $database = "test";

        $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE datefrom='$start_date' AND (timefrom<='$timevalue' AND timeto>='$timevalue')" );

         if(mysqli_num_rows( $result)>0){
                    return 1;
        }
         else{
             return 0;
         }
     }
```

And now it's working fine. Following is the output which I am getting. It is what I needed.
[image: Output]